# Imports in a source folder: The import cannot be resolved

Tags: java

I'm trying to import a package to a class to make some tests creating a particular class and to instance some objects.

So, I create a source folder (asdsad) and put a class in there, after I tried to import Produtos.GestaoDeContrato.Mapeamentos.Telas.* but doesn't work.

Is it possible to do this?

[image]

---

UPDATE 01
[image]

Thanks for the answers, I tried to do this, but I don't know if I did what you said, that is correct? Because doesn't works

Please, pardon my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to place all the java classes in the src folder of the project in eclipse unless you are trying to import from the jar file
2. but if you have multiple projects you can go to `properties>build
   path> Libraries > Add Class Folder > The select the required java
   package of the proj you need`.

Comment: would not be better if he would add those classes as a library?

Comment: Please add the java folder within your project, you have added the project folder

Answer (score 2):

If the class you are trying to instantiate is in a separate project as I can see, then you need to to add this class to your current's project class path.Or you can place  the class in the same project but in a different package !